# LLVM BPF backend doesn't put source file name on symbol table

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, bpf, ebpf

I'm now trying to extract source C file name from ELF object which is compiled from following C code by clang.

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t test(uint64_t a) {
  return a + 1;
}
```

When I specify amd64 as a backend, the clang generates the symtab like below

```
$ clang-6.0 -target amd64 -c test.c
$ readelf -s test.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 4 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     3: 0000000000000000    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 test
```

We can see the source file name is there. However, when I specify BPF as a backend, I see output like below.

```
$ clang-6.0 -target bpf -c test.c
$ readelf -s test.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 2 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 test
```

We can't see the source file name.

Does anyone know why is it and how can I solve the issue?

Working environment is Ubuntu18.04-LTS and clang version is 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final) which is installed via apt.

Comment: I was not able to find a document describing what are the expected fields in an ELF produced by BPF. AFAIK, the responsible method is the `addFilename` in `include/llvm/MC/MCAssembler.h` and the relevant field in LLVM is `ELF::STT_FILE` which uses the aforementioned data in `lib/MC/ELFObjectWriter.cpp`. I couldn't find any exceptions for the BPF backend. Maybe it's worth having a look if you're familiar with that backend.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is what I'm now looking for. However as you said, I couldn't figure out what makes difference. I also found that even other symbol information like symbol type or size is not generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a simple matter of configuration in LLVM. The `HasSingleParameterDotFile` variable in [`lib/Target/BPF/MCTargetDesc/BPFMCAsmInfo.h`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/9bcfd971896494c38ce7276424817263704c7450/lib/Target/BPF/MCTargetDesc/BPFMCAsmInfo.h#L33) controls whether or not the ELF file contains the source file symbol. It hasn't changed since [the first commit for the BPF backend](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/4fe85c75482f9d11c5a1f92a1863ce30afad8d0d) in LLVM and isn't explained in the commit message.

When I switch on the boolean and recompile LLVM + Clang, I get the following output:

```
$ readelf -s test.o
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 4 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     3: 0000000000000000    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 test

$ readelf -s test-bpf.o
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 3 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test-bpf.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 test
```

I'll try asking why it's configured that way on the mailing and, if there's no particular reason, I'll submit a patch to LLVM.

---

As you noticed (email exchange), the `HasDotTypeDotSizeDirective` variable in the same LLVM file controls the presence of symbol sizes and types in the ELF file:

```
# With HasDotTypeDotSizeDirective = true:
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 3 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test-bpf.c
     2: 0000000000000000    56 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 test
```

Comment: It seems this solves the problem. Thank you!

Actually, I'd like to use other symbol informations like symbol type or size and they are still missing. But it's another problem.

What I mentioned in this question is solved by this answer :)

Comment: I tested the solution you mentioned in your email for the other symbol information and appended it to my answer.